# Is there a proper way to cross join using yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

I'm doing a query for activedataprovider, which I'm going to use for the purpose of search. I need to use cross join. I used joinWith, but it complains about warehouse model not having relation with product. it was calling product. Are there any work around here so that it won't trigger the relation, since it's a cross join?

Other notes: Certain attributes like product_id, product.category, etc doesn't exist on the original model which is based on warehouse. Will it work on the fly if I just add public property/attribute variables or do I need a work around?

```
public function search($params)
    {               
        $query = Warehouse::find()->joinWith('product')
                ->select(['product_id' => 'product.id','warehouse.warehouse', 'product.category', 'product.product', 'min_stock' => 'coalesce(critical.min_stock, -1)'])
                ->leftJoin('critical', 'critical.product_id = product.id AND critical.warehouse_id = warehouse.id')
                ->where(['warehouse.id' => $this->_id]);

        $this->load($params);

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);        

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $query->andFilterWhere(['category' => $this->category]);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'product', $this->product]);        

        return $dataProvider;
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the relation error?

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas app\models\Warehouse has no relation named "product".

Comment: Is there any model called `Product` and is there any relation in DB between those tables?

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas it's a cross-join so there's no relationship between them.

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas Yes, there is a model called product.

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas I just realized that it's calling getProduct method. Are there any work arounds here?

Comment: I don't know, I never used cross joins, and getter (`joinWith`) might not help in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get Your Query record as array so you don't require to define relationship

```
public function search($params)
    {               
        $query = Warehouse::find()->joinWith('product')
                ->select(['product_id' => 'product.id','warehouse.warehouse', 'product.category', 'product.product', 'min_stock' => 'coalesce(critical.min_stock, -1)'])
                ->leftJoin('critical', 'critical.product_id = product.id AND critical.warehouse_id = warehouse.id')
                ->where(['warehouse.id' => $this->_id]);

        $query = Warehouse::find()
                ->select('product.id as id,warehouse.warehouse as warehouse, product.category as category, product.product as product, coalesce(critical.min_stock, -1) as min_stock ')
                ->leftJoin('product', 'warehouse.product_id = product.id')
                ->leftJoin('critical', 'critical.product_id = product.id')
                ->where(['warehouse.id' => $this->_id]);
                ->andWhere('critical.warehouse_id = warehouse.id')
                ->asArray();

        $this->load($params);

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);        

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $query->andFilterWhere(['category' => $this->category]);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'product', $this->product]);        

        return $dataProvider;
    }
```

Now you will get record as Array not as object.

Second way is, Define relation between Warehouse and Product in model using `hasOne()` or `hasMany()`

Answer (score 1):

For all the query that are difficult  (or impossibile)   to build using yii2 activeRecord or activeQuery functionalites  you can use findBySql

```
$sql = "select 
          product.id as id
          , warehouse.warehouse as warehouse 
          , product.category as category
          , product.product as product
          , coalesce(critical.min_stock, -1) as min_stock 
          from Warehouse 
          cross join product  
          left join critical on ritical.product_id = product.id AND critical.warehouse_id = warehouse.id
          where warehouse.id' = " . $this->_id  

 $model =  Warehouse::findBySql($sql );
```

Answer (score -1):

->joinWith('product', true,'cross join')

```
public function getProduct()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Product::className(), []);
}
```

Comment: Explain your solution.

Comment: public function joinWith($with, $eagerLoading = true, $joinType = 'LEFT JOIN')

Comment: ->joinWith('product', true,'cross join')
change LEFT JOIN to CROSS JOIN

Comment: return $this->hasOne(Product::className(), []); Warehouse model not having relation with Product, so the array is empty